# Pass value between Grandchild component and Parent component

Tags: angular, angular8

Using Angular 8 I have a few components as follows:

```
Parent 1 > Child 1 > ... > N Grandchild 1 

Parent 2 > Child 2 > ... > N Grandchild 2
```

Between `Child X` and `N Grandchild X` might have other components. So it can be more than 3 levels.

**Objective**
1. Set a Value in `N Grandchild 1` and use it in `Parent 1`.
2. Set a Value in `N Grandchild 2` and use it in `Parent 2`.

I am considering a few options:

1. Using an EventEmitter ([StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qezmme))

   **Problem:** Not working between Grandchild and Parent.

   It seems to work only one level up ... It is possible to make it work N levels up?

   ```
   export class GrandchildComponent implements OnInit {

     @Output() changeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

     ngOnInit() {
       this.changeEvent.emit('Hello');
     }

   }
   ```
2. Using a Service

   In this case I inject the Service in `N Grandchild X` to set the value and in `Parent X` to read the value.

   **Problem**:
   How to be sure that `Parent 1` reads the value set by `N GrandChild 1` and `Parent 2` reads the value set by `N GrandChild 2`? Is this possible?

Comment: it is better to use Subjects in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in another answer, which provides solution to use a Subject of some kind, but you face the issue that that subject and its value is shared across the app, **if** it's provided at root level.

One option is to provide the service at the parent level, which means that **the parent and all its descendants have the same instance of the service**, so therefore, if `grandchild1` emits a value for the subject, only `parent1` will receive that value, not `parent2`.

So what you would do, as mentioned, provide the service at the highest level you want, in this case I would assume it would be the `parent`:

```ts
import { MyService } from './my-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
  Parent:
  <p>Value from grandchild: {{value$ | async}}</p>
  <child></child>
  `,
  providers: [MyService] // <<<<<<<<<< add this (only in parent)!
})

export class ParentComponent { 

  value$;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.value$ = this.myService.subj$;
  }
}
```

and service could have:

```ts
private subj = new Subject();
public subj$ = this.subj.asObservable();

setValue(value) {
  this.subj.next(value)
}
```

And in the grandchild when you want to emit value, just call `setValue()` with the new value.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrtwqk?file=src/app/my-service.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a BehaviorSubject in a injected service in both components, one component listening on the BehaviorSubject. And the other emiting new values for the subject.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  subject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor() { 
    this.subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  }

  getObservable() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  updateValue(value) {
    this.subject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: But how to be sure that Parent 1 receives the value from Grandchild 1 and Parent 2 receives the value from Grandchild 2?  Does not BehaviorSubject always return the last value?

Answer (score 0):

**First Way:** You have to emit event on every level of chain, then only you will be able to get the event to the Parent component.

Parent 1(received) > Child 1(emit) > Child 2(emit) > N Grandchild 1(emit);

**Second Way:** Also for service you can create a message-bus kind of service, when you can specify from and to. So using those flag you can validate from where and for whom the data should be consumed by.

I personally think that you should go with the first approach.