# Angular multiple same children - passing different data

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a mat-table in angular where each row has a `app-mycomponent`. I want to send different data to different instance of the app-mycomponent.

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="greetingType">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> My header </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </table>
```

So each row in the table will have a `app-mycomponent`

Now, I want to pass different data to each `app-mycomponent`

I created an observable in service MyComponentService:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyComponentService {

  public myEvent$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  constructor() { }
}
```

and subscribed to it in mycomponent.ts:

```
  constructor(
    public myComponentService: MyComponentService 
  ) {
    this.myComponentService.myEvent$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

In the parent component, I do:

```
this.myComponentService.myEvent$.next(obj);
```

But whenever I do `.next`, all the app-component instances receive it. Whereas I want to send the data only to a particular instance.

How can I do this? Any way using observable or using `@Input`

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58977669/6294072

Comment: @AJT82 I don't know how that applies the case here. Please can you explain for this case?

Comment: To pass data to a component, you use an Input. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: in general I think you need pass as input the element `@Input() element` and `<app-mycomponent [element]="element">`

Comment: @JBNizet  Even if I use `@Input`, how do I send different data to each component?

Comment: @Eliseo Even if I use `@Input`, how do I send different data to each component?

Comment: @Eliseo showed you how: `<app-mycomponent [element]="element">`

Comment: @JBNizet But how do I have unique `element` for each row

Comment: The mat-table directive repeats the td for every row. Each time with a new element. https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#2-define-the-column-templates

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure I completely understood your problem, but what if you could specify the data with a function insted of element using `@Input()`?

for example:

```
  <app-mycomponent [element]="getData()"></app-mycomponent>
```

and in your `ts` file:

```
getData(){

    //here you can subscribe to your service or just provide data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your app-component, so I`m going to do the most simple table that include a component. Begings with the simple example of mat-table. So I create a component like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'row-component',
  template:`
    {{element.position}}{{element.name}}{{element.weight}}{{element.symbol}}

  `
})
export class RowComponent {
  @Input() element:any;
}
```

Our mat-table need an array of object, so, we are going to do

```
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA.map(x => {
    return {
      header: x
    };
  });
```

And we create a table with an unique td

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="header">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Header</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let row">
       <row-component [element]="element.header"></row-component>
       </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

See that we pass "element.header" and that displayedColumns are

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["header"];
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnorjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the service on component level. As a result a new instance of the service will be created with each component.

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  providers:  [ MyComponentService ]
})
export class MyComponent
```

But providing a service on component level is usually not a good practice.